# Pandas Series not plotting to timeseries chart

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, data-visualization

I have a data set of house prices - [House Price Data](http://publicdata.landregistry.gov.uk/market-trend-data/house-price-index-data/UK-HPI-full-file-2017-08.csv?utm_medium=GOV.UK&utm_source=datadownload&utm_campaign=full_fil&utm_term=9.30_17_10_17). When I use a subset of the data in a Numpy array, I can plot it in this nice timeseries chart:

[image: Desired chart BUT using Numpy Array]

However, when I use the same data in a Panda Series, the chart goes all lumpy like this:

[image: The lumpy chart using a Pandas Series]

How can I create a smooth time series line graph (like the first image) using a Panda Series?

Here is what I am doing to get the nice looking time series chart (using Numpy array)(after importing numpy as np, pandas as pd and matplotlib.pyplot as plt):

```
data = pd.read_csv('HPI.csv', index_col='Date', parse_dates=True) #pull in csv file, make index the date column and parse the dates
brixton = data[data['RegionName'] == 'Lambeth'] # pull out a subset for the region Lambeth
prices = brixton['AveragePrice'].values # create a numpy array of the average price values
plt.plot(prices) #plot
plt.show() #show
```

Here is what I am doing to get the lumpy one using a Panda series:

```
data = pd.read_csv('HPI.csv', index_col='Date', parse_dates=True)
brixton = data[data['RegionName'] == 'Lambeth']
prices_panda = brixton['AveragePrice'] 
plt.plot(prices_panda)
plt.show()
```

How do I make this second graph show as a nice smooth proper time series?

*** This is my first StackOverflow question so please shout if I have left anything out or not been clear ***

Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: Shouting here ;-) You may want to read [mcve] and [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples). You wouln't usually ask people here to download a 50Mb file to reproduce your issue. Instead, generate the data inside your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The date format in the file you have is Day/Month/Year. In order for pandas to interprete this format correctly you can use the option `dayfirst=True` inside the `read_csv` call.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.read_csv('data/UK-HPI-full-file-2017-08.csv', 
                   index_col='Date', parse_dates=True, dayfirst=True)
brixton = data[data['RegionName'] == 'Lambeth']
prices_panda = brixton['AveragePrice'] 
plt.plot(prices_panda)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

When you did `parse_dates=True`, pandas read the dates in its default method, which is month-day-year. Your data is formatted according to the British convention, which is day-month-year. As a result, instead of having a data point for the first of every month, your plot is showing data points for the first 12 days of January, and a flat line for the rest of each year. You need to reformat the dates, such as

`data.index = pd.to_datetime({'year':data.index.year,'month':data.index.day,'day':data.index.month})`