# Plotting Pandas Series only showing partial values

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot a Pandas Series with lots of samples:

```
In [1]: vp_series = pd.Series(data=raw_df.Count, index=raw_df.Timestamp)

In [2]: len(vp_series)
Out[2]: 17499650

In [3]: vp_series.index[-1]
Out[3]: 559888625359
```

When I try to plot this series, the produced plot looks like this:

```
In [4]: vp_series.plot()
```

[image]

Clearly not all data points are plotted, and max value on the x axis is only about `1.75e7` instead of `5.59e11`.

However, when I try to plot the same data in Julia (using Plots and the PyPlot backend) it produces the correct figure:

[image]

What should I do here to make the plot contain all the data points? I tried to search in the doc of matplotlib and Pandas.Series but found nothing.

Comment: I suggest you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It might be clear for you that data points are missing. But we only see what you post here - and for me it is just a dataset that has irregular spacing.

Comment: Maybe this can help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47355526/pandas-series-not-plotting-to-timeseries-chart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason is that the way I used to create the `pandas.Series` is wrong. Instead of

```
vp_series = pd.Series(data=raw_df.Count, index=raw_df.Timestamp)
```

I should be using

```
vp_series = pd.Series(data=raw_df.Count.values, index=raw_df.Timestamp)
```

The first way is causing my series to contain a lot of missing values (`NaN`) which are not plotted. The reason is well explained in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35818873/pandas-series-creation-using-dataframe-columns-returns-nan-data-entries).

I know I didn't ask my question properly and I appreciate all the comments.